# Hibernate allocationSize ignores "allocationSize"

Tags: java, hibernate, sequence

How to put in order hibernate and database sequence generation?

My entity:

```
package kz.open.sankaz.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SEC_ROLE")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecRole extends AbstractEntity implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEC_ROLE_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "SEC_ROLE_ID_SEQ", name = "SEC_ROLE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

I wrote that "allocationSize" is 1. But Hibernate generates wrong query:

```
Hibernate: create sequence public.sec_role_seq start 1 increment 50
```

It makes a problem not only while you are inserting a new data, it also makes problem when you are running database migration queries. For example, I wrote the next line:

```
create sequence public.sec_role_seq start 1 increment 1;
```

and Hibernate conflicts with it:

```
The increment size of the [SEC_ROLE_SEQ] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1]
```

How to solve it? Please, help!

Comment: @Kayaman excuse me, but I didn't get what you mean

Comment: Since the name of the sequence seems to be `sec_role_seq` in the query, but it's not the same name in `@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SEC_ROLE_ID_SEQ"`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing generator in the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SEC_ROLE")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecRole extends AbstractEntity implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEC_ROLE_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "SEC_ROLE_SEQ",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "SEC_ROLE_SEQ"),
                    @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                    @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
            }
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```